# Validation Accuracy Increases But Training Accuracy Doesn't

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, validation, accuracy

The training accuracy of my model is not improving though validation accuracy improves steadily. This is weird abnormal behaviour and I just can't figure out what's wrong. Here are some graphs to help you give an idea.

**Training Cost**

[image]

**Training Accuracy**

[image]

**Evaluation Accuracy**

[image]

**Training And Evaluation Accuracy Both**

[image]

**Note** -- I have not used any deep learning framework. I am running this on a **from scratch neural net** which is taken from [Michael Nielsen's book.](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com)
Its working fine, I have tested it on other datasets. And the problem which I am working on is a binary Image classification task. Details are below --

**Architecture** - [3072, 60, 60, 2] -- two hidden layers of 60, 60 neurons 
**Training Data** - 9000 images of dimensions (32,32,3) of two classes 
**Validation Data** - 500 images of two classes 
**Activation** - Sigmoid 
**Learning Rate** - 0.005 
**Mini Batch Size** - 10 
**Epochs** - 35 
**Lambda** - 0.0 (No regularization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in 1 epoch , you go through 850 mini batches of 10 examples each..

It could be one or more of the following :-

1.) Your training/validation set is biased. Try picking validation set randomly out of training set, if you haven't .

2.) Your cost function. What is it? That too may have influenced your results..

3.) The weights that you initialized may not be good. Try using some other initial weights.

4.) You may have done some error in plotting graphs.

Try plotting the cost function for both training and validation sets. And see if their behaviour differ from the plots of accuracy.

Also, try changing batch size. Maybe 10 is too small..

Comment: you know what, I made some predictions using this model and submitted that to kaggle, and I got 82% accuracy. As by chance probability is 50%, it signals that model is working, at least up to some extent.  I used standard cross entropy cost function and I chose training data so that it has an almost equal number of both classes, then I randomly shuffled it and selected 500 of those images for the validation set.